# ASP.net mvc 4 how to use a dropdown menu?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ASP.net MVC 4 (coming from webforms) and so I am a bit confused on how to do a certain type of functionality.

I created a dropdown box by using

```
<select>
@for(var item in ViewBag.Items)
{
    <option value="@item.ID">@item.name</option>
}
</select>
```

and let's say I create an "add" button.

```
<input type="submit" value="Add" />
```

and I have a table, let's call the table "cars," with a column called "CarID."

What I want to happen is to hit the add button, a new row gets added to the cars table with the car ID the user selected in the dropdown box.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3

Comment: Well we will need a bit of extra details to point you in the right direction, thing is you could very well add an item to the collection in your model, either client side with Javascript, or server side with good old c#, both approach are valid and quite easy with MVC. Where are the rows in your car table coming from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to setup a `form` around the control as well as a few html attributes on the `select`.

```
<form action="/Cars/Add" method="post">
   <select name="carId">
     @for(var item in ViewBag.Items)
     {
       <option value="@item.ID">@item.name</option>
     }
   </select>

   <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

Now, create a new controller named `Cars` and add an action `Add` as such.

```
public class CarsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Add(int carId)
    {
        // TODO : Validate the carId
        // TODO : Do the DB stuff to insert the car as you would in winforms
        return View("AddComplete"); // or whatever view
    }
}
```

The above example generates a form which will submit a variable called `carId` to `Add` action.  The action handler will then validate and add it to the database.

What you have to remember that with HTML there is no state, ie, each time the page is loaded everything relevant has to be either passed in or loaded.

These are some of the fundamental concepts of c# MVC development so it might be worth the time to read up the basics :-

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

Comment: Or for a javscript approach: http://jsfiddle.net/WQh2G/ ;-) (Didn't see [tag:javascript] so not going to provide as an answer)

Comment: @BradChristie from the question I got the impression it was to store an entry in the database, hence the postback.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC a better decision would be to move all logic from View to controller:

If you are having car model:

```
public class car
{
    public string carname {get;set;}
    public int carID {get; set;}
}
```

Than you may create `SelectList` in your controller action method:

```
public ActionResult CreateNewRow()
{
    //**create selectList in controller
    var carlist = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var cars = from n in db.Cars
              select new SelectListItem
        {
             Text = n.carname,
             Value = n.CarID.ToString()
        };
    foreach (var item in cars)
    carlist.Add(item);

    ViewBag.cars = cars

    return View();
}
```

Than in your view you'll just need something like following:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.carID, (SelectList)ViewBag.cars)

    <input type="submit" value="ok" />
}
```